# Setting a TextArea value from a Database field

Tags: html

I have a database that stores messages. The message field is 640 characters long. Having tried to manage it with (substr($Message,0,110)) substrings and concatenation I decided to use a Textarea and came up against the issue of updating the present text by inserting the message on file. I have looked at your online help and the answers were not entirely convincing. So I played and after a couple of hours this worked:

```html
<textarea name="MessageA" id="MessageA" rows="8" cols="80">' . $MessageA . '</textarea>
```

I know it doesnt cater for special characters but appears to be a simple solution. Is there anything wrong with this technique.

Comment: I don’t understand how ' . $MessageA . ' is html?

Comment: Sorry should have explained it is HTML generated by a php program.

Comment: I’m confused on what you are looking for. Do u want to display your data from data base on the front end using a text area?